# Why does LassoCV mean square error depend on alphas interval?

Tags: cross-validation, linear-model, lasso, scikit-learn, regularization

I am tuning alpha coefficient in Lasso regularisation to get best result on cross-validation:

```
alphas = np.arange(1,200, 1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
lasso=LassoCV(alphas=alphas)
r=lasso.fit(X,y)
plt.plot(alphas,lasso.mse_path_)
```

This gives me following picture:

[image]

I want to see minimum of the red curve,enlarge alpha interval twice (np.arange(1,400, 1)) and rerun the code:

[image]

Why curves' coorientations depend on alphas array size??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.alphas_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) for the $X$ axis.

Your plot

```
plt.plot(alphas,lasso.mse_path_)
```

implicitly assumes the order is the original one of `alphas`. This is a logical assumption, but it happens to be incorrect - in your case, it's outputting results corresponding to a reverse order of your `alphas`. If you use

```
plt.plot(lasso.alphas_, lasso.mse_path_)
```

your plots will do what you want.